# TeamCity - passing parameter values with whitespace to command line

Tags: teamcity

I'm passing some TeamCity parameters to the command line build step. The problem comes when the parameter value contains spaces, e.g.:

```
%env.TEAMCITY_BUILDCONF_NAME%  ---> My TC Project
```

Is there a way to replace white spaces with some other character, for example underscore?

```
%env.TEAMCITY_BUILDCONF_NAME%  ---> My_TC_Project
```

Comment: Command line script usually can access environment variables. Probably it makes sense to rewrite it this way.

Answer (score 3):

You can typically keep using the white spaces if you wrap the parameter in double quotes:

`%program.files.dir%` => `C:\Program Files (x86)`

Executable: `dir`

Parameters: `"%program.files.dir%"`

Comment: Yes, I've tried that but it won't work in my case. The command evaluates whitespace as a start of a new argument.

Comment: Quoting it *should* work. What is the command you're running? What is its error message?

Comment: what if parameter value itself can contain double AND single quotes?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how to replace spaces with underscore, but I had an issue with whitespaces.
In a TeamCity build step, I was trying to run an sqlcmd as **Executable with Parameters**

```
-S %sql_server% -U %sql_username% -P %sql_password% 
-i "custom_script.sql" -d "%custom_db%"
-v DealerName="%DealerName%"
```

where DealerName was "Great Dealer Ltd" but it didn't work with white spaces, even with double quotes.

It fixed the issue by setting it as a **Custom Script** like

```
sqlcmd -S %sql_server% -U %sql_username% -P %sql_password% 
-i "custom_script.sql"  -d "%custom_db%"
-v DealerName="%DealerName%"
```

and (thanks to my boss suggestion) it worked like charm.

Even if is not the precise answer to your question, it could be useful for similar issues.

Answer (score 0):

String given below worked for me.

```
%env.TEAMCITY_BUILDCONF_NAME%  ---> "My\ TC\ Project"
```